# XML Doctype validation with JBoss 7.1.1.Final AS

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, jboss, java-ee-6

While developing a **J2EE** application on **JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final**, I've been defining some configuration files as follows:

`xa-orchestrator-ds.xml` (note that my datasource is a **MySQL** instance):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC
        "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 5.0//EN"
        "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">
<datasources>

    ...

</datasources>
```

`jboss-web.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-service_5_0.dtd">
<jboss-web>

    ...

</jboss-web>
```

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    ...

 </web-app>
```

This configuration causes a runtime exception related to XML validation:

```
12:28:50,676 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MIUR_PRISMA-2.1-BusinessLayer.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MIUR_PRISMA-2.1-BusinessLayer.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "MIUR_PRISMA-2.1-BusinessLayer.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Connection reset
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Connection reset
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwFromIOE(StreamScanner.java:699)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader.findDtdExtSubset(ValidatingStreamReader.java:480)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader.finishDTD(ValidatingStreamReader.java:341)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.skipToken(BasicStreamReader.java:3341)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:1958)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1102)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1125)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:106)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:80)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:687) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:658) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1323) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at com.ctc.wstx.util.URLUtil.inputStreamFromURL(URLUtil.java:146)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.DefaultInputResolver.sourceFromURL(DefaultInputResolver.java:254)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.DefaultInputResolver.resolveEntity(DefaultInputResolver.java:92)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader.findDtdExtSubset(ValidatingStreamReader.java:471)
    ... 14 more
```

Indeed, by removing the doctype definition from `xa-orchestrator-ds.xml`, it works fine.

Which is the properly configuration by including right doctypes?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with J**Boss Application Server 7.1.0.Final** you have the ability to deploy a `-ds.xml` file following the schema:

http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_1.xsd

**Eg:**

```
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema">
  <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDB" pool-name="MySQLPool">
      <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/as7db</connection-url>
      <driver>mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar</driver>
      <pool>
          <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
      </pool>
      <security>
          <user-name>user</user-name>
          <password>...</password>
      </security>
  </datasource>
</datasources>
```

**EDIT:**

Another way is add the `schemaLocation`

```
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_1.xsd">

</datasources>
```

Comment: But the doctype is still missing also in your configuration.

Comment: @vdenotaris XML documents can have a reference to a DTD or to an XML Schema. http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_howto.asp

Comment: @vdenotaris I added more information in the answer, maybe can be help.